# How to get Reponse over postman post method as Json format

Tags: json, spring-boot, postman

I want to see the response as Json format, I was doing user signup and the return value is just string "sign up" but now I want the return or the user data to be shown as Json format in postman

Comment: Go to postman, and choice the _JSON_ format as response, and you should get it.

Comment: Extending on @codrelphi 's answer, you'll find it in response body window, the right most tab should yet be `TEXT`, change it to `JSON`

Comment: I already put my out put in post man as a json it just my code has a return value it displays that, but iI want to show me the data as json

Comment: Along with above suggestions, if it's a spring boot app, you can use @RequestMapping(path="/myEndPoint",produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON), again depending on which annotations you are using!